# merge data frame only keep one observation

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames: guests and addresses.

"guests" contains names of people and corresponding person-level data. People are organized by Family ID, such that multiple people in the same family share a Family ID, like this:

```
## Guests data frame looks like this:
Family.ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)
Names <- c("Person_A", "Person_B", "Person_C", "Person_D", "Person_E",
           "Person_F", "Person_G", "Person_H", "Person_I", "Person_J")
list <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C")
guests <- data.frame(Family.ID, Names, list)
```

"addresses" contains the families with their addresses, also labeled by Family ID, like this:

```
## Addresses data frame looks like this:
family <- c("Person A, B, & C", "Person D & E", "Person F, G, & H", "Person I & J")
ID <- c(1,2,3,4)
address <- c("family 1's address", "family 2's address", "family 3's address", "family 4's address")
addresses <- data.frame(ID, family, address)
names(addresses) <- c("Family.ID", "Family", "Address")
```

**My goal is to add the variable guests$list to "addresses".** I tried merging "guests" and "addresses" like this:

```
both <- merge(guests, addresses, by = "Family.ID")
```

From the merge, I get:

```
  Family.ID Names     list  Family              Address
        1   Person_A    A   Person A, B, & C    family 1's address
        1   Person_B    A   Person A, B, & C    family 1's address
        1   Person_C    A   Person A, B, & C    family 1's address
        2   Person_D    A   Person D & E        family 2's address
        2   Person_E    A   Person D & E        family 2's address
        3   Person_F    B   Person F, G, & H    family 3's address
        3   Person_G    B   Person F, G, & H    family 3's address
        3   Person_H    B   Person F, G, & H    family 3's address
        4   Person_I    C   Person I & J        family 4's address
        4   Person_J    C   Person I & J        family 4's address
```

But what I want to get is just "list" added to "addresses", like this:

```
  Family.ID Family              Address             List
        1   Person A, B, & C    family 1's address  A
        2   Person D & E        family 2's address  A
        3   Person F, G, & H    family 3's address  B
        4   Person I & J        family 4's address  C
```

Do I need to do something to reshape the data frames before merging?

Comment: Try `unique` ie. `unique(both[-2])`

Comment: Or just `merge(unique(guests[-2]), addresses, by='Family.ID')` -2 is to remove the second column which is `Names` that is not showed in the expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge` with `unique` rows of "guests" data after removing the `Names` column (`guests[-2]`)

```
merge(unique(guests[-2]), addresses, by='Family.ID')
#   Family.ID list           Family            Address
#1         1    A Person A, B, & C family 1's address
#2         2    A     Person D & E family 2's address
#3         3    B Person F, G, & H family 3's address
#4         4    C     Person I & J family 4's address
```